# Picking two points on the 3d model surface to measure distances

Tags: selection-tools, measurement

I'm a blender n00b and this may be a wrong tool for the job, but I've found some great features in Blender (like the [caliper](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-268103.html) add on), so I'm pretty sure there's a way to easily (or at least bit easier) select two surface points of a loaded 3D .ply model somehow instead of moving the caliper/ruler points and its x y z axis individually one at a time?

Is there such a tool in Blender (or anything standalone) for selecting points from a surface of a loaded 3D model and measuring the distance of those selected points please?

Any explanation for how to do it any faster in Blender, instead of moving x y z axis of caliper (or **ruler/protractor** tool) one at a time attempting to align them to a surface of a loaded 3D model, or in any other tool that's able to measure that would be greatly helpful and appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite tool for measuring things is the [measureit addon](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/measureit).

Once the addon is installed and enabled, simply enable *Show* in *3D view > Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) *> Measureit tab*. Then select the vertices you want to measure and click *Segment*. You can edit and delete individual measurements in the *Properties Region* (<kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: it can be downloaded here: https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/measureit

Comment: @cegaton I just went to get the link, only to be distracted by a notification for this comment :P

Comment: Thank you four answers both, the only trouble I have is that my mash has a really large number of vertices (about 230k, 440k faces, etc.) so in edit mode it's really slow to select two vertices among so many...is there such a thing in Blender that can reduce vertices but estimate the loss in precision of remaining points, or do it somehow without loss, that'd be great. TIA