# Where to suggest Blender additions and fixes

Tags: interface, screw-modifier

Where can I suggest fixes and additions to someone who works on Blender? I have a lot of suggestions for problems I ran into:

1. Screw modifier needs fit curve and fit length settings just like
   array
2. Array settings for objects going in a circle instead of adding
   empties and rotating them (so annoying)
3. Better drawing and texturing tools
4. Equation objects like golden rectangle generator
5. Specific measurement tools with shortcut keys
6. A data path for a curve's length
7. Many more options for Blender game engine (optional integration of object constraints, turn more Python commands into nodes for people who can't code. we don't have enough node options)
8. Official freaking object motion tools (animation nodes?..)
9. Time dilation tools with nodes (entire animation nodes?) instead of scaling keyframes
10. Better autoretopologizing than remesh. 
    If any of these exist, then I apologize, but I know most of these don't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request and not a real support question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Place to put Feature Requests?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6253/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41641/2843

Answer (score 5):

For bugs that need fixing use the [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug). For feature requests, there is no official place, but you can try [Right-Click Select](https://rightclickselect.com/p/), the [bf-funboard](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard) mailing list or simply ask on [Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/) where other users can give you feedback and build on your idea.

Please note that Stack Exchange is not a suitable place for bug reports or feature requests, hence this question should be closed.